# Knockout text bind to a json object

Tags: knockout.js

I have a ViewModel and inside I have an observable. Every time I click on a button I fill this observable with ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Contracts/Details/' + id,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        self.showContractDetail(true);
        self.contractDetail(data.contract);
        alert(self.contractDetail().Partner.Surname);
    }
});
```

The alert shows the correct value. But in my html I have:

```
<h2>contract number <span data-bind="text: contractDetail.ContractNumber"></span></h2>    
<h4>partner: <span data-bind="text: contractDetail.Partner.Surname"></span></h4>
```

But nothing is shown. If I replace `text: contractDetail.` with `text: contractDetail().` then only the first binding is shown. That is: it shows `contract number: 236578` and `partner: <empty>`. If I comment `data-bind="text: contractDetail().ContractNumber"`  then the surname appears.

Any help on why this is happening? I don't want to bind contractDetail to my viewModel. I want my viewModel to contain an observable with complex contract details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make a JSFiddle showing the problem? I'm answering this question now because what I have to say is too much for a comment, but I can't really verify if it fixes anything if I can't reproduce the issue.

You are correct that `text: contractDetail.` should be changed to `text: contractDetail().`. Do any errors show in your console when you do this?

Another way would be to wrap both these lines of html in a virtual binding:

```
<!-- ko with: contractDetail -->
<h2>contract number <span data-bind="text: ContractNumber"></span></h2>    
<h4>partner: <span data-bind="text: Partner.Surname"></span></h4>
<!-- /ko -->
```